# Twilio API: retrieve SIP Interface pricing

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Using Twilio's API, I would like to retrieve the data displayed on this page: https://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing/us but I cannot find the call that I need to make in order to retrieve the "SIP INTERFACE" pricing:

[image: SIP INTERFACE pricing]

Are these values even available through Twilio's API? All I could find was Voice, Messaging, PhoneNumbers and Trunking.

Comment: Are you asking if there's an API to get the pricing? What is your use-case why you would want to do that?

Comment: Yes, I am asking if there's an API call to get the "SIP Interface" pricing as it is displayed on the link I posted. The reason is the same as with the other pricing, for which Twilio has an API already: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/pricing

Comment: I understand, but how about you ask your colleagues at Twilio if they know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIP-Interface has, as of now, a flat prices of $0.004 and doesn't have country-specific pricing like PSTN or ESIPT. Therefore, it's not included in the API.